# How to execute a expect script while connecting to a ssh server

Tags: expect

For example, now I have a "root.exp" expect script as following:

```
spawn ssh user@ip
expect "Password:"
send "password"
```

Then, the `expect` command I want to send to this ssh server is stored in another expect script file *branch.exp*, which for example is as following:

```
expect ">>"
send "ls"
```

My question is, how to call this *branch.exp* in *root.exp*? For example, something like following in the *root.exp*:

```
spawn ssh user@ip
expect "Password:"
send "password"

*call* branch.exp
```

Answer (score 1):

As Johannes said, you can use the source command. The [Expect and TCL mini reference manual](http://inguza.com/document/expect-and-tcl-mini-reference-manual) says:

> **source**     Procedures and variables can be stored in other files and read using the source command. As the file is read, the commands are executed.

```
Example:

source ~/def.tcl
```